# Until end of turn effects and Doubling Season

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-modern

Alright so I'm pretty sure doubling season and like cards don't affect actions related to +X/X until end of turn or -x/X until end of turn because it doesn't physically say counters. My friend on the other thinks the opposite. For instance I have doubling season up, opponent gives me a -1/1 counter it would give my creature -2/2 due to doubling seasons wording, I give the negative counters to Quillspike to get +3/3. Here's where the difference comes in. He believes that for each negative counter given to Quillspike, Quillspike would receive +6/6 until end of turn even though they aren't worded as counters. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is not correct. As you identify, [Doubling Season](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoubling%20Season%5d)'s second ability only cares about counters being placed on permanents you control.

If your opponent put a -1/-1 counter on a permanent you control, Doubling Season applies and two -1/-1 counters are placed instead.

[Quillspike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bQuillspike%5d)'s ability cost doesn't place counters on permanents. It removes them. Quillspike's ability doesn't place counters, it just gets +3/+3 until end of turn. Neither part of this ability interacts directly with Doubling Season.

However, because Quillspike is "fuelled" by -1/-1 counters, Doubling Season does ensure that you get double the fuel (as long as the creature receiving the counters isn't reduced to 0 toughness). You still have to pay the mana costs to activate Quillspike's ability more than once.

Comment: That's what I thought but he was very adamant that with doubling season quillspike would get a total +12/12 from the two -1/1 counters. Thank you for your answer! Just needed clarification.

Comment: Yeah, there's an important distinction between counters (which tend to last) and temporary (such as end of turn) or static (being constantly boosted) boosts to power and toughness.